# ある配列と配列を組み合わせて、新しい配列を作りたいのですがうまくいきません。

Tags: php

１ヶ月のうちの特定の日にちの配列（11月）と
曜日によって割り当てるフルーツ用の配列があります。
これを使って該当する曜日に特定の配列を入れ込みたいのですが、何故か２３で止まっています・・
どうしてなのかわかりません。

（また今後　　1週目、2週目ごと　といった制限をかける実装を行う予定です）

```
$fruitArray = array (
            'tue' => 'banana',
            'fri' => 'apple',
            'sat' => 'orange',
          );



$dayArray=
 array (
  1 => 'tue',
  2 => 'wed',
  4 => 'fri',
  5 => 'sat',
  7 => 'mon',
  8 => 'tue',
  9 => 'wed',
  10 => 'thu',
  11 => 'fri',
  12 => 'sat',
  14 => 'mon',
  15 => 'tue',
  16 => 'wed',
  17 => 'thu',
  18 => 'fri',
  19 => 'sat',
  21 => 'mon',
  22 => 'tue',
  24 => 'thu',
  25 => 'fri',
  26 => 'sat',
  28 => 'mon',
  29 => 'tue',
  30 => 'wed',
)
```

```
        foreach($dayArray as $day){
          if(isset($fruitArray[$day])){
            $result[] = [$day,$fruitArray[$day]];
          } else {
            $result[] = [$day,null];
          }
        }
```

結果は何故か２３で止まってしまいます。

```
 array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'tue',
    1 => 'banana',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'wed',
    1 => '',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 'fri',
    1 => 'apple',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => 'sat',
    1 => 'orange',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    0 => 'mon',
    1 => '',
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    0 => 'tue',
    1 => 'banana',
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    0 => 'wed',
    1 => '',
  ),
  7 => 
  array (
    0 => 'thu',
    1 => '',
  ),
  8 => 
  array (
    0 => 'fri',
    1 => 'apple',
  ),
  9 => 
  array (
    0 => 'sat',
    1 => 'orange',
  ),
  10 => 
  array (
    0 => 'mon',
    1 => '',
  ),
  11 => 
  array (
    0 => 'tue',
    1 => 'banana',
  ),
  12 => 
  array (
    0 => 'wed',
    1 => '',
  ),
  13 => 
  array (
    0 => 'thu',
    1 => '',
  ),
  14 => 
  array (
    0 => 'fri',
    1 => 'apple',
  ),
  15 => 
  array (
    0 => 'sat',
    1 => 'orange',
  ),
  16 => 
  array (
    0 => 'mon',
    1 => '',
  ),
  17 => 
  array (
    0 => 'tue',
    1 => 'banana',
  ),
  18 => 
  array (
    0 => 'thu',
    1 => '',
  ),
  19 => 
  array (
    0 => 'fri',
    1 => 'apple',
  ),
  20 => 
  array (
    0 => 'sat',
    1 => 'orange',
  ),
  21 => 
  array (
    0 => 'mon',
    1 => '',
  ),
  22 => 
  array (
    0 => 'tue',
    1 => 'banana',
  ),
  23 => 
  array (
    0 => 'wed',
    1 => '',
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

正常な動作です。
配列のキーを指定しなかった場合、0から連続する番号がふり直されます。
`$dayArray`には24個の要素しか登録されていないため、番号が23までとなってしまいます。
配列のキーを維持したい場合は、下記のように配列のキーを指定してあげるとよいです。

```
        foreach($dayArray as $key => $day){
          if(isset($fruitArray[$day])){
            $result[$key] = [$day,$fruitArray[$day]];
          } else {
            $result[$key] = [$day,null];
          }
        }
```

参考になれば幸いです。

Answer (score 0):

参考までに、文字列データだけの一次元配列なら str_replaceで置換することも出来ます。

```
$dayArray=
  array (
    1 => 'tue',
    2 => 'wed',
    4 => 'fri',
    5 => 'sat',
    7 => 'mon',
    8 => 'tue',
    9 => 'wed',
    10 => 'thu',
    11 => 'fri',
    12 => 'sat',
    14 => 'mon',
    15 => 'tue',
    16 => 'wed',
    17 => 'thu',
    18 => 'fri',
    19 => 'sat',
    21 => 'mon',
    22 => 'tue',
    24 => 'thu',
    25 => 'fri',
    26 => 'sat',
    28 => 'mon',
    29 => 'tue',
    30 => 'wed',
  );

$new_array = str_replace(array('tue', 'fri','sat'),array('banana', 'apple', 'orange'),$dayArray);
$new_array = str_replace(array('mon', 'wed','thu','sun'),'',$new_array);
print_r($new_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
$result = array_map(fn($v) => [$v, $fruitArray[$v] ?? null], $dayArray);
```